# javascript multiple events not firing

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html element that is suppose to call 3 JS functions as its onchange event, however; it only fires off the first function. I am stumped as to why it is not doing it.

```
<select id="dlist" onChange="func1(); func1(); func3()"/>

func1 = function(){
//code
}

func3 = function(){
//code
}

func2 = function(){
//code
}
```

What could this issue be?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/BjbDg/. It calls `func1` and `func3`, just like you have it in the attribute (note that you are calling `func1` **twice**).

Comment: One reason why the other methods are not called could be that you have an error in `func1` which terminates the execution. But that's just guessing. As you can see in my example, if I take the code as you posted it, it calls the functions.

Answer (score 3):

```
<select id="dlist" "onChange=func1(); func1(); func3()"/>
```

You are wrapping the entire attribute in quotes.
You want

```
<select id="dlist" onChange="func1(); func1(); func3()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `onChange="func1(); func1(); func3()"`.

Move the quote.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
var slt= document.getElementById('dlist').onchange= func1; func1;func3
```

or

```
var slt= document.getElementById('dlist').onchange= myAll;


function myAll(){

func1();
func2();
func3();

}
```

Comment: That's just completely wrong. This assigns the return value of `func1` to `.onchange`.

Comment: This will now assign `func3` to `.onchange`... slightly better, but only `func3` will be called when the event is triggered, not all three functions. *edit again:* This will assign `func1` to `.onchange`, so only `func1` will be called when the event is triggered (referring to the first snippet).

Comment: The second one will work, but you don't have to create a named function. You could do `el.onchange = function() { funct1(); func2(); funct3(); };`. The first one (and everything else before) is (logically) incorrect.